# liquid is not formatting dates when used with jekyll

Tags: ruby, liquid, jekyll, date-formatting

```
{{ post.date | "%B %e, %Y" }}
```

is being converted to

```
2011-11-10 00:00:00 -0500
```

My versions are listed below:

```
 % ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p0 (2009-01-30 revision 21907) [i686-linux]

 % gem list | grep liquid
liquid (2.3.0, 2.0.0)

 % jekyll --version
Jekyll 0.11.0
```

I tried googling the issue but didn't find anything useful. There was a [bug opened](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/8) for this same issue but it was closed without any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to ruby 1.8.7 solves this problem

```
 % ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do it with ruby-1.9 is

```
{{ post.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}
```